# 12 V relay with a switch to control fuel pump relay

Tags: switches, relay, automotive

Is it possible to control a fuel pump relay with another relay with a switch?

I want to touch a capacitive switch before turning the ignition key all the way to turn the fuel pump on.

Then when I turn the car off, I have to touch the capacitive switch again to turn the fuel pump on so I can start the car.

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Comment: A relay is just an electrically-operated switch, so it can be used whereever you would use a switch.

Comment: the second and third paragraphs are irrelevant to the question